# Total function Problem

Tags: calculus, functions

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { Consider the following function } f \text { defined over } \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}} \\ {\qquad f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{\log (x) \cdot \cos (x)} & {x>0} \\ {0} & {x \leq 0}\end{array}\right.}\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { (a) Determine whether f is one-to-one. }} \\ {\text { (b) Determine whether f is onto. }} \\ {\text { (c) Determine whether f is total. }} \\ {\text { (d) Determine ranges for x and y so that f is total but not one-to-one. (e) Determine ranges for x and y so that f is one-to-one, onto and total. }}\end{array}
$$

Clearly $f$ is not one one since all negative values of $x$ maps to $0$ . It seems onto since $\log_{x}$ is surjective.

Comment: What is a total function?

Comment: Total function is just function whose value is well defined over all domain which is true here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is function onto?

Comment: It is onto. Use IVP to show that $f$ maps $(0, \infty)$ onto $\mathbb R$.